# Savon SOAP client finds 0 operations on this WSDL

Tags: soap, wsdl, savon

I'm using Savon v 2.3.3 as my Rails application's SOAP client, and it appears to find zero operations on one of the wsdls which I query. (I've had no problems on for other wsdls which my application queries.) When I view the wsdl manually, it appears well formatted, and I find the operations that I seek:

http://dev.service.xrae.com/direct.svc?wsdl

Can you tell me what I need to change or what's unusual about this wsdl?

Answer (score 0):

This wsdl doesn't have 'binding' section. Articles that can help:

- http://predic8.com/wsdl-reading.htm
- http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_wsdl_binding.asp

Adding

```
<wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_XraeDirectApi" type="tns:XraeDirectApi">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <wsdl:operation name="AddCase"/>
</wsdl:binding>
```

can fix it.